# Unipolar stepper motor and a MCU

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, stepper-motor

I have been trying to steer unipolar stepper motor (5V, 0.7A) using microcontroller powered only by USB (5V or smthing like that). The motor clicking got louder but the motor doesn't move yet.

I tried to lower resistance of R1, R2, R3 and R4 and motor cliks got louder, but when I completely removed these resistors it again clicked more silently... Does anyone have any idea on how to make this motor turn as it should?

I used ohm meter to measure the internal resistance which was 5Ω and I am affraid to lower R5, R6, R7 and R8 any more as my external power supply isn't very strong plus I might damage transistors...

When I tested the motor all by itself with no microcontroller It did turn if approximately 0.3A current flow through the windings. Maybee my:

- transistor isn't fully opened
- current through the windings in motor is too low
- my external power supply can't handle it (this is not an option for me :S i have to make it work lol)

Schematic:

[image]

Closeup of the right part of the schematic:

[image]

---

EDIT: This is the circuit schematic after I consulting with you guys:

[image]

I hope this will do the trick.

Comment: What model are the transistors T1-T4?  Could you post a link to the datasheet?

Comment: Also mention the mcu you are using, best case it can provide about 20-30mA from I/O pins, so even if you are using a Darlington transistor the base resistor is way too low.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev Transistors are this ones: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BC546-D.PDF @ alexan_e I am using LPC3141 here is the datasheet: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC3141_43.pdf

Comment: There are a few things I'm not clear about. You say the supply is from USB but your schematic shows a 12V supply. The motor rating is 5v/0.7A with coil resistance 5 Ohm. You place each coil in series with a 37 Ohm resistor so the voltage that reaches the motor is 5/(37+5)=1.42v is this just for testing purpose? Also the shown 12v supply rating is 0.31A but your motor current rating is more than double that.

Comment: @alexan_e USB supplies only microcontroller and is 5V. It can only be seen from the first image (top left corner). +12V is an external adapter capable of producing only 0.31A which is half as much as the motor needs. But in order not to fry my motor too I chose to settle for a lower current. This is a testing circuit correct. Really nice deduction btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the transistor rating of BC546 in the datasheet, `Collector Current − Continuous IC 100 mA dc`.

Your mcu specs mention an absolute max or 4mA as output current (you have already exceeded that with the base resistor you have used).

You need to select a more powerful transistor and a high gain Darlington would suit your needs, a device like [TIP120](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf)

Your mcu is a 3.3v device and a Darlington transistor needs about 1.5v between base-emitter so a resistor of about (3.3v - 1.5v)/0.003A = 600 ohm should do or slightly higher to 620 Ohm

---

If you don't have a Darlington available you can use two discrete transistors in a Darlindton configuration to increase the current gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8BfeY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I've uses a 1A transistor for Q1.
You'll need four of these, one for each coil.

Comment: So problem with the collector current is that it must not exceed 100mA for BC546? Does this means I fried all of my transistors? So I guess if I would use TIP120 I wouldn't fry it and could drive the motor. In the last paragraph did you mean a base resistor 600Ω? Do I then need R5-R8 ?

Comment: @71GA BC546 collector current is must not exceed 100mA (continuation rating) but in order to get that with a low voltage drop across collector-emitter you need to saturate the transistor and for this to happen you need to provide about 1/10 to 1/20 of the output current to the base, but your mcu can't source that much current. In any case 100mA in not enough for your application so BC546 will not do. By the way, you should also add 4 back EMF protection diodes, each one for collector (cathode) to the ground (anode). Yes the resistor I calculated for about 3mA from the I/O pin is about 600 Ohm.

Comment: The micro is probably smoked and will need replaced.

Comment: Now I am scared. Why would the micro be smoked (It is mounted on an embeded board and maybee it had some protection diodes)? One more question. Using optocoupler like this one http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Toshiba%20PDFs/TLP627,-2,-4.pdf is out of the question too because of it's Collector current 150mA right? I found this transistor in my workshop http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/fairchild/BD243B.pdf. **It seems I could use it** but for the sake of my microcontroller **please confirm**.

Comment: @71GA The opto output can't drive the motor directly, it can only be used as a driver for a power transistor. BD243 can provide up to 6A to the motor but it's not a Darlington so the gain is low. Also the base current calculations are not the same since Vbe is about 0.7v. Try to find a Darlington transistor or you can use a discrete Darlington, see the edit above.

Comment: @alexan_c That is not a Darlington, the collectors should be connected together for a Darlington. A MOSFET might be easier.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You are right. Regarding the mosfet it may have its own set of problems depending on the switching rate he intends to use.

Comment: Ok so I went to the electronics shop today and bought TIP121: http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/fairchild/TIP121.pdf It has an integrated diode already and gets saturated at base-current voltage 2.6V. So will this one do fine? I allso bought 1A diodes. OH! And the micro is smoked...

Comment: @71GA TIP121 is fine. So the mcu got damaged completely or just the specific pin or maybe one port? There is a lesson to be learned, always check the max current that a device can provide before trying to utilize the I/O pins. Another case that may damage the chip is when all pins are below the max current individually (which seems fine) but in total add to over the max rating for the port of the mcu supply, so make sure to check that parameter too in case you drive devices like seven segment displays.

Comment: I don't know what parts of MCU got fried because I can't even connect to it. But this means USB peripheral got hit too - which is quite a bad hit. I think it is completely fried. There were no diodes on the embedded system to protect GPIO11,12,13,14 pins... Those 1A diodes I bought will have to do. I will have to pay 15€ for a repair now and am wondering if there is still any chance that any other component got fried (remember GPIOs were connected directly to the MCU). What about current flowing into the mcu - it could allso fry the MCU.

Comment: @71GA I think the main cause was the I/O over current but I can't be sure of what got damaged. The purpose of the diodes is to protect the transistor, I don't see how they can help protect the MCU. Maybe in the future you should consider using a buffer like 74HC244 between the board and external circuit, at least when you are experimenting.

Comment: Can't a current for example flow from +12V through N junction and then P junction directly into a base which has lower voltage afterall?

Comment: @71GA the 12v are connected to the collector of a NPN, the anode is at the base and the cathode at the collector side, current can't flow from the collector to the base and to the mcu I/O. Also a diode in series with the I/O would only work in one direction, for example when the output was high. What about the low state, the diode would not conduct so essentially the output would be +3 or floating.

Comment: Please check my EDIT and confirm if this will do.

Comment: @71GA Yes, that will do, it feeds the base with about 2mA. In case the motor doesn't move you may need to lower the resistor values connected in series with the motor (R5/R6/R7/R8). Also note that these four resistors currently (37 Ohm) have to dissipate about 3W each so I hope they are not 1/4W type

Comment: Just to let readers know. This works! Thank you all who participated.